# How to return some value from rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake-task

How can I return some value from a `Rake` task in ruby.

Sample code:

```
namespace tasks
    task task1: :environment do |task|
      log = "Running task"
      puts log
      log << "Done"
      return log # suggest how to do this
    end
end
```

I am running the rake task as: `Rake::Task['tasks:task1'].invoke`. How can I get the return value in a variable as follows:

```
result = Rake::Task['tasks:task1'].invoke
```

Comment: Looking through the source code for `rake` this appears to be not possible. Ultimately the return value for a rake task is determined from `Task#execute` which has a `nil` return value. You can take a look here. https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/task.rb#L270

Comment: Instead of calling other task result, in task1 I set `result = 'something'` and in task2 I can read the variable. Consider I created `result` variable outside task scopes, something like `result = nil` before any namespace/task. This is, assuming you want a task result in other task.

Comment: In the past I have resorted to storing a flag somewhere either in a database table or in a txt file that can be read back in when needed

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the task result in other task:

```rb
config = ''

task :load_config do
  config = 'some config' # this could be reading from a file or API
end

# this tasks depends on the other
task use_config: [:load_config] do
  puts config
end
```

Then:

```
$ bundle exec rake use_config
some config
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Try aborting with an error message and catching that.

Depending on what you're trying to return, you could try aborting the task with an error message, which would be "catchable" from where you invoked the task. You could then see what the error message was.

**Your Task**

```rb
namespace :tasks
  task task1: :environment do |task|
    log = "Running task... "
    puts log
    log << "Done!"
    abort( log )
  end
end
```

**Running Your Task**

```rb
begin
  Rake::Task[ "tasks:task1" ].invoke
rescue SystemExit => exit
  puts exit.message #=> "Running task... Done!" 
end
```

It's not exactly elegant but depending on what you're trying to return it could handle your needs.

Answer (score 0):

### Call the Rake's `action` directly.

*Using @vigo's example because it's simple.*

```rb
task :return_a_value do
  '123'
end
```

```rb
result = Rake::Task['return_a_value'].actions.first.call

puts result #=> "123"
```

I found this out by digging through the various methods of the Rake Task in the console and this appeared to work without having to run the task twice, like @vido's answer.

**However, the only caveat I've found is that I couldn't figure out how to pass arguments to the Rake Task using this method. Using `.call( "myargument" )` didn't work. If you can figure out how to do this, I'd be grateful if you shared it. Thanks!**

#### Update: Figured it out.

After a little more experimentation, I figured out how to use this method while passing arguments to the Rake Task. You just have to pass a `Hash` of the arguments as the second parameter and `nil` as the first, like so:

```rb
task :return_a_value, :mystring do
  mystring
end
```

```rb
result = Rake::Task['return_a_value'].actions.first.call( nil, { mystring: "hellow there" } )

puts result #=> "hellow there"
```

It has the added benefit of naming the parameters you pass to the Rake Task, which is a nice bonus.

---

##### Versions

- Rails: 7.0.7
- Ruby: 3.2.2

Comment: One caveat I noticed when using this is that it didn't seem to preload my models. I ended up going a different direction but you may need to load in your environment manually.

Answer (score -1):

You can exit a rake task with a code and then check that with $?

But perhaps rake might not really the right tool for this job.

Answer (score -1):

```rb
task :return_a_value do
  '123'
end

task :hello do
  result = Rake::Task['return_a_value'].invoke.first.call
  puts result
end
```

now call:

```sh
$ rake hello
123
```

Comment: this runs task `return_a_value` twice. You can check this if you add a print before the return

Comment: if you add more prints, you'll see more executions. thats why .invoke.first (from an array) important. when you inject print statement, it will be another statement to run. try with double print lines. such as print 'a' (new line) print 'b' (new line) and '123'

Comment: `invoke` will run the task and store it in an array, and `first.call` will run the task one more time

Comment: they are all proc in the array. any suggestions? @JuanJoséRamírez